# Anime series where people have powers based on their fetishes

Tags: story-identification, anime

The series had a guy who, when he would take a picture with his camera, it would cause explosions and a guy who could use his blood as a weapon or wings.

There is a reference that the guy with the camera is only attracted to women while using his camera, and a girl who can only get turned on while holding her gun.

Comment: This sounds ridiculous, and therefore I am intrigued.

Comment: I highly recommend you check it out Monty, it is thoroughly enjoyable. It's a short series but worth finding. Speed Grapher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Speed Grapher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_Grapher) (2005).

Definitely this is *Speed Grapher*. Really good, if totally strange. It is about what you said it is about. You gave a perfect summary of the show.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/198/Speed_Grapher):

> Ten years after the Bubble War, the dichotomy between the rich and the poor in the world becomes more prominent and Japan is no exception. The rich seek to satisfy their desires and derive pleasure for themselves, and Tokyo has materialized into such a city as a result. Saiga, once a war photographer, works for Hibara Ginza in the capitalist state of Tokyo. He infiltrates the Roppongi Club, a secretive base located in the red light district of the city, to collect information about them. However, he was caught in the process and brought forward to a girl called Kagura who was in the midst of a ritual. **His contact with Kagura awakens his special ability: the power to make things explode when photographed.** In order to unravel the mystery behind the Roppongi Club and Kagura, Saiga begins his solitary battle.

Opening (mildly NSFW):

Comment: That anime was very good, and it's definitely the one the OP wants. Lots of cool characters, as the show is based on vices taken to the extreme. And a badass cop that goes in alone and guns blazing while yelling "Self-defense!" and "Don't make me self-defense you!" while kicking the crap out of everyone was definitely a bonus!

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I watched this anime years ago with a buddy and he forgot what it was called lol. I have been trying to find it for years. Thanks again, this is exactly what I was looking for.